# Joi error for object not listing all errors at once

Tags: reactjs, joi

I have an array of object where data possibly be empty, like below

```
[
    { firstName: "", lastName: "" },   // [0]
    { firstName: "", lastName: "" }    // [1]
]
```

I am trying to validate this.

my schema is

```
let service = Joi.object().keys({
    firstName: Joi.string()
      .required()
      .error(new Error("first name is required")),
    lastName: Joi.string().required("last name is required"),
  });

 let services = Joi.array().items(service);
```

on `services.validate(inputFields)` I am only recieving error for first name of object [0]

[see this for the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srnZb.png)

only when first name[0] is filled, error for lastname[0] is shown. similarly when both firstname[0] and lastname[0] is filled, error for next item's firstname [1] is shown.

ie, the array will look like

```
[
        { firstName: "nabeel", lastName: "mhd" },   // [0]
        { firstName: "", lastName: "" }    // [1]
 ]
```

and error then will be

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfI7r.png)

what I need is to list all errors so that I can pass the message in required areas.

Answer (score 1):

[That's a known issue.](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/2595)

You can get the same result if you set [abortEarly](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.7.0#anyvalidatevalue-options) to `false` and use [.messages](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.7.0#anymessagesmessages):

```
Joi.object({
  firstName: Joi.string()
    .required()
    .messages({  
      'string.base': `"firstName" should be a type of 'text'`,
      'string.empty': `"firstName" cannot be an empty field`,
      'any.required': `"firstName" is a required field` 
    }),
  lastName: Joi.string()
    .required()
    .messages({ 
      'string.base': `"lastName" should be a type of 'text'`,
      'string.empty': `"lastName" cannot be an empty field`,
      'any.required': `"lastName" is a required field` 
    }),
}).options({ abortEarly: false })
```